# setreuid() fails with Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, c, kernel, freebsd, user-permissions

I am trying to change the real UID of the process with the code below

```
int ERN2=setreuid(euid,m_ruid);
printf("something went wrong with setreuid %s\n", strerror(ERN2));
std::cout<<"error no for setrugid"<<ERN2<<"\n";
if ( ERN2 == 0)
{
.....
}
```

The `m_ruid` is root(0) and the `euid` is accepted ID, but when i get the result of the `setreuid()` its always -1 and I've used  `strerror()` which says "Operation not permitted" adding to that I can able to change the realGID `setregid()` yet changing the UID always fail can anybody shed some light.

I am on FreeBSD.I wonder why that its been happening even we gave root as one of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The manual page is pretty clear:

> The setreuid() function returns the value 0 if successful; otherwise the value -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.

This is how error returns work for almost all system calls. They don't return the errno, they just return `-1` or equivalent on error and set the global variable `errno`.

If that wasn't clear, try `strerror(errno)` and see what you get.

Comment: i get it also it says "Operation not permitted" i wonder why the setreuid() operation is been failing even when we give the root ID as one of its param.

Comment: @FallingFromBed Is the process that does this running as root? (or in any other way permitted to change its uid)